# How to make phone number as optional in PayPal donate button

Tags: button, paypal

I've created a PayPal donation link from my business account. I've copied the "Shareable link" and I'm simply opening that link from a button on my website. For users with no PayPal account and using a credit card, the default payment page has the users contact phone number  field as "Required". How do I make the phone number as optional? I don't want the users to cancel their donation because of this stupid requirement that I need their phone number. I do not. I just want them to donate whatever amount they are comfortable with.

I banged my head in the PayPal support community without any success. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A phone number is required information for sending a payment via PayPal.

For normal PayPal payments, you can set whether a contact phone number will be part of a PayPal transaction. This setting is within the receiving account's [Website Payment Preferences](https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website).

However, regardless of whether a contact phone number is part of the transaction (and in that case provided to the receiver of the payment), a phone number is still required to send payments via PayPal. Using an obvious dummy phone number or one not associated with the funding source being used to pay (such as a credit or debit card) will result in greater likelihood that a transaction will be declined by either PayPal or that card company. This is by design and intended functionality for more secure payment processing.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! So it's clear to me now that the contact number is required. I just hope that doesn't stop people from continuing the donation process. Thanks again for a quick response! Really appreciated it.

Comment: But it stops user to make donate, and a lot of another fields like address and so on. Donation must be simple, but PayPal donation is difficult for user. It is fact. 150 users click donate button, 2 of them paid...